# selecting points within the specific distances

Tags: php, mysql

i have many deals in my database. i want to seleect some specific deals from the database by sending arguments "lat" "lon" and the radius..
this query isnt working what is wront with it..

```
  require('includes/connection.php');  // defines $dsn, $username, $password      
  $lat = $_GET['lat'];  // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
  $lon = $_GET['lon'];  // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
  $rad = $_GET['rad'];  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers
  $R = 6371;  // earth's radius, km
  // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
  $maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
  $minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
  // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
  $maxLon = $lon + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
  $minLon = $lon - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));

  // convert origin of filter circle to radians
  $lat = deg2rad($lat);
  $lon = deg2rad($lon);
  $sql = "    Select * From  From deals
      Where lat>$minLat And lat<$maxLat
        And lon>$minLon And lon<$maxLon
    Where acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lon)-$lon))*$R < $rad";
echo "Query =".$sql;  
  $points = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "isn't working". is it not delivering any results, is it giving an error message...? Please be a little more specific. What you could try right away is printing the sql query string and executing the resulting statement via e.g. phpmyadmin?

Comment: You cannot just pass variables with $ inside the query, you have to either use sprintf, concatenate or use similar solutions. See the examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @Viruzzo: that actually should work as far as I know (see e.g. http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/Variable_substitution.html)

Comment: @Viruzzo Actually, you can do that.  I do it all the time, though it's not particularly fool-proof.

Comment: My bad, it's one of those bad practices that I must have forgotten.

Comment: @Viruzzo I agree that it's really not the best thing to do.  But so long as you know it's limitations, it can be gotten away with.

Comment: Did my answer answer your question?  Or do you still need help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small change required replace second `where` with `and`.We cant use two `where` clause here. aSAlso two `from` clause are not allowed.

Try with below query.

```
Select * From  deals 
Where lat>$minLat 
And lat<$maxLat 
And lon>$minLon 
And lon<$maxLon 
and acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(lat))+cos($lat)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lon)-$lon))*$R < $rad";`
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because you have 2 "WHERE" statements.  You can probably just change the second "WHERE" to an "AND".

Comment: Two from are also not allowed.